# takePicture failed when picture is taken automatically but works on button click

Tags: android, android-camera

So I am trying to create an app that takes a picture as soon as the application opens. When I run code that does that i get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1141)
    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1086)
    at com.me.phonespy.StealthActivity.takePic(StealthActivity.java:110)
    at com.me.phonespy.StealthActivity.go(StealthActivity.java:116)
```

Code:

```
public class StealthActivity extends Activity implements PictureCallback {
Camera cam;
FrameLayout preview;        
CamPreview camPreview;
File pictureFile;
Bitmap bmp;
Matrix matrix;
Button pb;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stealth);
    initCamPreview();
    pb= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


}
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    pb.performClick();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{

    releaseCameraAndPreview();

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    preview.removeAllViews();
}
void initCamPreview()
{
    cam=openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread();
    cam.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    preview= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    camPreview= new CamPreview(this, cam);
    camPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(camPreview);
    preview.addView(camPreview);
}

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    if (cam != null) {
        cam.release();
        cam = null;
    }
}void takePic()
{
    cam.takePicture(null, null, this);

}

public void go(View view)
{
    takePic();

}


@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{
      //handles saving image
     }
```

I get  the same takePicture failed when I put `cam.takePicture(null, null, this);` in the `onResume` or `onCreate` however it works and takes the photo when I press the button that calles `go(View view)`

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Preview must be started before you can take a picture. Where is your `startPreview()` ? In addition, they all run in main thread, you cannot make callback work instantly when you  make initialization and register the callback.

Comment: Startpreview occurs in new CamPreview() when surface is created. So if I were to pause and take the photo after 1sec it should work?

Comment: The main thread runs with a infinite loop. so, assume you initialize everything in first loop, you can trigger something in second loop. use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to run takePicture.